# Autoencoder and Neural Network Overfitting in terms of parameter number?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, overfitting, autoencoders

I have `1100` sequences for 2 classes. Of them `400` are from one `class 1` and `700` are from `class 2`. I have used an one hidden layer auto-encoder of `2` neurons to capture my features. My initial features are tri-grams for each sequences. So, for each sequence I have `6860` tri-grams. As a result most of my input vectors are sparse vectors.

Now, if I calculate the parameters for this network, I have

```
6860 * 2 = 13720 paramters (1st layer)
2 * 6860 = 13720 parameters (2nd layer)
-----------------------------------------
           27440 parameters (in total)
```

Now, that is way too many parameters in comparison to my number of data points. Hence, I have used a dropout value of `0.98`, on `layer 1->hidden layer` as well as `hidden layer->output layer` which makes the number of parameters `13720 * 0.02 =  274` on each layer and in total `548` parameters.

Now, after training, I tried the encoder on my test data of `500` sequences, and extracted the hidden layer of 2 dimensional data. Then I use that data on another 5 neuron single hidden layer neural network to classify. My results are really good in that I am getting around `90%` accuracy.

My question is am I overfitting in my autoencoder? Am I overfitting by using another neural network? I am worried about my low number of data points. Does my use of dropout seem sensible?

Comment: Overfitting is only indirectly quantifiable as how well the model does on holdout data. You have the holdout data. How well does your model do?

Comment: As I said, I am getting 90% accuracy on my test data. But my question is, am I doing something wrong in my overall strategy i.e number of layers, number of neurons, dropout percentage etc.

Comment: Is that 90% figure dramatically lower than what you achieved on your training data? That's the definition of overfitting. The number of layers and neurons is specific to each data set; if this configuration does better than other models, it's fine. Accuracy isn't a great measure of model fitness though. For classification tasks, look into cross-entropy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am worried that I am calculating the parameter numbers wrong, and my network has more parameters than number of data samples even after using Dropout. Does my calculation seem correct?